# If we have 5 six-sided dice what are all the possibilities of getting 3 of one number and 2 of a second number?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Would it be as simple as $\displaystyle {6 \choose 2}\times{5 \choose 3}\times{5 \choose 2}$?

Comment: Are the two numbers specified? The number of ways to get three $1$s and two $2$s is not the same as the number of ways to get three of one number (which could be any number) and two of some other number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pick any three particular dice:  $\dbinom{5}{3}$

Select any one number now which appears in the selected three dice $\dbinom{6}{1}$

Now pick remaining two dice:  $\dbinom{2}{2}$

Select any of the remaining number which appears in the selected two dice $\dbinom{5}{1}$

So, number of ways is

$\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{5}{1}$

Comment: how  u got  nCr(6,3) times nCr(6,2)?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but there are a few misses. First off, you're not choosing $2$ values freely, you're choosing one value of which to have three dice, and then one value of which to have two. Therefore it's $6\cdot 5$ instead of $\binom 62$.

Second, you only need to choose which of the five dice are to be three together, and the two remaining will be chosen automatically. Therefore it's $\binom 53$ instead of $\binom53\binom52$.

So the end result is $6\cdot 5\cdot\binom53$.